# Listing CVS Attic/Delete files

Tags: cvs

How to get a list of deleted files in CVS (ie files in Attic).

Answer (score 0):

In a perfect world the following should give you what you want:

```
cvs -q rlog -sdead -rHEAD -SNR ModuleName
```

However, it only works partially with my CVSNT installation, possibly because CVSNT treats the reserved `HEAD` symbol not as the single revision at the tip of the default branch but instead uses it to identify the entire trunk branch.

In this case that means that besides files that are currently deleted you will also get files that were resurrected again since they were deleted or files that were initially added on a branch (as those will also have a "dead" revision at 1.1). You might want to try it with the vanilla CVS (instead of CVSNT) anyway as I seem to remember that treating `HEAD` as a branch rather than as a revision is a CVSNT-specific idiosyncrasy...